# accessing global frames in a user defined function

Tags: python, function, frame

```
a = 4
def foo(x):
    a = 10
foo(2)
print(a)
#prints 4
```

The code above doesn't change `a`

```
a = 4
def foo(x):
   return a + x
result = foo(10)
print(result)
#prints out 14
```

I don't quite understand how these two act differently. The second one, the global variable obviously affects the local variable in `foo`. But if I change `a` in the first one inside the `foo`, nothing happens to `a` in the global frame. What is happening?

Comment: It's helpful to know that Python looks up variable names using something called the [LEGB scoping rule](http://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/355230). The result of that search also determines which ones it considers to be local when they're encountered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to **change** a global variable inside the function, you should use `global` keyword:

```
a = 4
def foo(x):
    global a
    a = 10
foo(2)
print(a)  # prints 10
```

Also see:

- [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Comment: In fact, it's _always_ safe to use `global` to access a global variable, even if you're not assigning to it, or not sure, or can't remember the rule. And in many cases, it makes your code clearer, too.

Answer (score 3):

> What is happening?

In the first case, you have two different variable named `a`: One (`a = 10`) is part of the function's scope and can only be accessed from inside the function.  This variable is deleted after the function returns.  The other variable (`a = 4`) is part of the outer (global) scope and is not affected in any way.

In the second snippet, there is only one variable `a`.  This variable is in the global scope, but it can also be accessed (read) from inside the function.  It can't be changed from inside the function, though.